# "TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument" when executing Pool.map() with kwargs

Tags: python

I'm creating a `functools.partial` for a function with `**kwargs`.

```
from functools import partial

def foo(required, **kwargs):
    return required + str(kwargs)

_foo = partial(foo, "hello", bar='baz')
```

Both `foo("hello", bar='baz')` and `_foo()` print the expected output:

```
In [4]: foo("hello", bar="baz")
Out[4]: "hello{'bar': 'baz'}"
In [5]: _foo()
Out[5]: "hello{'bar': 'baz'}"
```

I attempt to run this `partial` as part of a `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool()
results = pool.map(_foo, range(2)) # Run the _foo partial twice
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

How can I execute `foo` in a pool and provide the desired keyword arguments?

Comment: What calls to `_foo` do you expect to take place? it is calling `_foo(0)` and `_foo(1)`, which is easy to verify are invalid, regardless of the multiprocessing.Pool.

Comment: *doh!* I'd forgotten that the `Pool.map` call puts the second argument into the function! Write this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: If it was calling `_foo(0)` and `_foo(1)` wouldn't the error say `TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
` instead of 3 given?

Comment: Never mind, apparently Python 3 TypeErrors give you more specific information than Python 2 TypeErrors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first bind the positional argument `required`, and then in the `map` call, another positional argument is passed implicitly (0 in first call, 1 in second call).

Those are, of course, invalid calls, as is easy to demonstrate regardless of the pool:

```
_foo = partial(foo, "hello", bar='baz')  # required is bound to "hello" here
_foo(0)  # no more position arguments are allowed...
=> TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: I think I overlooked this because, in my situation, I don't actually care about the iteration number, `[0, 1]`, so I just overlooked them.